# Как запустить скрипт python с помощью xp_cmdshell из sql-server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, cmd, powershell

На сервере установлен python 3.8.5. Если запускать файл bot.py из командной строки, то все работает. Но мне нужно запускать этот файл через SQL SERVER 2012 по триггеру добавления новой строки в таблицу.

Пробовал по-разному:

Через PowerShell

```
DECLARE @CMDSQL VARCHAR(1000)
SET @CMDSQL = 'PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\TELEGRAMGATEWAY\MSSQL_TELEGRAM+sa\Databases\Problem\> D:\telegram.bat'
EXEC xp_CMDShell @CMDSQL
```

Выбивает ошибку

```
"PS" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Через python

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell ' python "C:\Python\Telegram\bot.py" '
```

Выбивает ошибку

```
"python" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Другим способом через python

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell  'python -S TELEGRAMGATEWAY\MSSQL_TELEGRAM -d Problem -i C:\Python\Telegram\bot.py'
```

Та же самая ошибка.

Как мне запустить этот скрипт без ошибок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это может быть двухэтапный процесс:

(1) Создайте файл * .bat из двух строк:

**c:\bot_launcher.bat**, И убедитесь, что он работает в командной строке сам по себе.

Я использовал c: \ ... только для примера.

```
cd c:\Program Files\Python38\
python "C:\Python\Telegram\bot.py"
```

(2) Запустите c:\bot_launcher.bat в SSMS, используя его полностью квалифицированный путь:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'c:\bot_launcher.bat'
```

Полезная ссылка: [Установка Python и запуск сценариев Python из SQL Server SSMS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5036/installing-python-and-running-python-scripts-from-sql-server-ssms/)